# Why is the struct byteCounter being considered as "io.Writer"?

Tags: go

In this code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type byteCounter struct {
    w     io.Writer
    count int64
}

func countingWriter(w io.Writer) (io.Writer, *int64) {
    var bc = byteCounter{w, 0}

    // here why is &bc a "io.Writer" and not bc.w cause bc.count is int64
    return &bc, &bc.count

}

func (bc *byteCounter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    ncount, err := bc.w.Write(p)
    bc.count += int64(ncount)
    return
}

func main() {
    bc, count := countingWriter(os.Stdout)

    bc.Write([]byte("Hello World"))

    fmt.Println("\n", *count)
}
```

Why is `&bc` a "io.Writer" type and not `bc.w` I am confused because I see  `bc.count` is `int64`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is `&bc` a "io.Writer" type

Because your `byteCounter` type satisfies the `io.Writer` interface by virtue of having a `Write()` method with the proper signature.

> and not `bc.w`

`bc.w` is *also* an `io.Writer`.

> I am confused because I see `bc.count` is `int64`.

`bc.count` is irrelevant here. Your `byteCounter` type can contain any data, of any type. The only thing that's relevant to satisfying an interface whether it has the necessary method(s).